# Query database from

Tags: php, mysql, database, xcode

I have a mysql database with information about some events (date, location, description etc).
I use a PHP file to connect to Xcode. All this works well and my table on xcode lists all the events.

I now want to add a UIDatepicker in Xcode and allow users to choose a date and a list of events will appear. My question is: What is the best way to do this? Should this be done in xcode or in my php file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: obviously UIDatePicker... how user will handle date in PHP in xcode?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you are fetching data from server through PHP API's, you must be parsing and manipulating (saving) that data perhaps in a database or in an appropriate data structure. Now you want to show listing of events specific to some date picked through a data picker, obviously you need to do that in your app code. Implement `UIDatePicker` in your application code and manipulate the data w.r.t to the date selected through `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: I will add a UIDatePicker. But should the data be manipulated in my xcode code or php? Sorry if its a silly question. newman.

Comment: @newman: The data will be manipulated in your objective-c code.

Comment: @newman: If your API is sending Event Date with every record, you just compare this date with the UIDatePicker date, and populate your table only with records that occured on that date.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this problem myself. Below is the code to insert a date into the database. Extracting it from the database is similar, though my code for that currently is messy. Basically you create a timestamp from the datepicker, send it as a string to php. In php I then convert to an int then a datetime object then insert.

Probably better way but this works fine.

xcode for iphone...

```
-(void)upload{
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];
NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
self.thisNumber=[timeStampObj stringValue];
NSLog(@"date...%@",thisNumber);
[self postMessage:thisNumber];
}

-(IBAction)push:(id)sender{
[self upload];
}

-(void)postMessage:(NSNumber*)thisNumber {
NSMutableString*postString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kTimestamp,thisNumber]];
[postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"postString...%@",postString);
NSMutableURLRequest*request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
postConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

php …

```
$date=$_GET['date'];
$ts=intval($date);
$other=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts);

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO fifteen VALUES('','$other')"))
echo "successful insert";
else
echo "failed";
```